# custom jquery gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery

I am creating a template. All xhtml/css work is done but a jquery image gallery. There are too many jquery galleries around and i do not know how to customize them according to situation

This is a three column template..First column has navigation. second column will have image selected from thumbnails of 3rd column. Also there are up/down buttons in 3rd column that rotate thumbnails. ON clicking a thumbnail image should load in 2nd column's image div.

Do i have to provide any more info?

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Wht jquery gallery plugin can do this? I tried a few plugins but could not get desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't actually asked a question, I'm going to assume you're asking how to get started. You also haven't given your HTML structure, so I'm going to have to assume that too.

HTML structure

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img id="main_image" />
    <div>
        <img src="image1-thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img src="image2-thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img src="image3-thumbnail.jpg" />
        <img src="image4-thumbnail.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Start off by creating a jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.gallery = function () {

    };
})(jQuery)
```

This ensures that your code will be completely re-usable and won't cause naming clashes if you want to use it with another framework in future. Next you want to add a click event to each thumbnail to make it modify the SRC of the main image:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.gallery = function () {
        this.find($(this).attr('id') + '>div>img').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('img').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            var mainImageSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('-thumbnail','');
            $(this).parent().siblings('img').attr('src',mainImageSrc);
        });
        return this; // jQuery plugins should (nearly) always return this to make them chainable
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Finally call your function:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#gallery').gallery();
});
```

This code should provide the basic functionality. I'll leave you to work on making the thumbnails scrollable, and if you really feel up to it, making a fade between images (hint: you need two img tags, with CSS to lay them on top of each other, then `.animate()` the opacity to fade between them). Hopefully this should get you going though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but my question is 'is not there a vertical jquery gallery?? that can be integrated with template?'

Comment: have wasted a lot of time with jquery galleries and finally realized i should write my own code. code above was very helpful to start. will share here after i m done. thanks

Comment: I'm all for avoiding re-inventing the wheel, but sometimes a custom solution is the only way of getting exactly what you want. Glad this helped you get started. If you're having trouble doing anything specific with the gallery, just ask another question. To make sure you get a good answer, remember to include all relevant code and make sure the question is specific.

Comment: what is fn ? and why use this ?

Answer (score 0):

Galleriffic Is Your Solution

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html

Its very Customizable and Easy to Integrate.